# How to write readme files that are automatically included into the Doxygen output?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, restructuredtext

Conceptually along the lines of [restructuredtext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText), I want to distribute readme files throughout my different source directories and then have [Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) read and include those readme text files as part of the generated Doxygen output.

How is this done? Or do I need to spoof Doxygen by creating a pseudo C file like:

README.h:

```
/** 
My big long readme file describing how this library 
was created and how it should be used
*/
namespace foo_readme { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just using HTML output you can just use the [`HTML_EXTRA_FILES`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_files) field of the doxygen configuration file.

If you have a plain text README file just add it to your program directory manually.

You can also spoof a `.h` file with the tag [`\mainpage`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmainpage) to populate the index (main) page of your doxygen output.

Answer (score 0):

In doxygen.config

Add FILE_PATTERNS = README

Add INPUT = foo_dir

Then add comments to the foo_dir/README

/*!

* opus

* @brief amaze me

* @details do something amazing

*/

namespace README { }

Answer (score 0):

If you create your README as a .md file, like a Bitbucket Readme, it will be included automatically by Doxygen in the Related Pages. You can also set USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE to a .md file for your front page.